# Master Project with Subprojects - need to share master but without the subprojects included

Tags: ms-project

I have a master project which contains 11 sub projects. Whenever I send the master project to anyone, I have to send all the 11 sub project MPPs out to them too.

Is there a way of creating the master so that I dont need to send the sub projects too?

Ideally, I want to be able to take a "snap shot" of the master, so the sub projects are no longer referenced from seperate MPPs, and instead are just ready only data within the master. [UPDATE: when I say "snap shot" I don't actually mean using the snapshot function in MS Project]

Hope that makes sense! Happy to clarify!

Thanks
Confused Planner

Comment: Do you absolutely have to send the MPP? Could you not send a rolled-up snapshot image of the Master plan?

Comment: Have to send the MPP as it's used by a central PMO. How does a rolled-up snapshot work anyway?

Comment: Roll up the tasks to the their highest level (by minimising all the sub-tasks) and then do a Snapshot (Task->Copy->Copy Picture) and paste it into an email or a document and send that... If PMO is the audience then I would expect that they would need the sub-projects anyway so what they ask for doesn't seem unreasonable to me.

Comment: Thanks for explaining that Marv. We still need a solution to be able to have the master plan as a standalone plan without having to send all the other 11 subproject plans. Any ideas???

Comment: Try creating the master without linking to the subproject files.  Uncheck the Link to Project checkbox when you insert the subprojects to create a "static" master.

Comment: Thanks for that JulieS! I can't seem to find the checkbox to de-link, I'm using MSP2010. Any guidance would be hugely appreciated :-)

Answer (score 1):

Double click on the subprojects in the master project and go to the advanced tab. Un-tick the box "Link to project", this removes the link to the subproject (**BE WARNED** if you unlink it you can not link it back, so do not click save, do a **SAVE AS**). The subproject tasks becomes tasks in the master project.

If you have shared resource pool you will want to remove this link, otherwise all resource will be double booked.

I have found that this is the best workaround if you need to send you master project out using email etc without sending multiple files. This obviously means this file will not update with changes made to the subprojects.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom field to flag which tasks you want to share, filter by the flag, hide the flag column and print it in PDF

Cheers